# Is there recommended way to return an address in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, void-pointers

I have to get an address back from a function. I'm using a 32bit system and will be, this code does not need to be portable, however, I would consider that a benefit.

Of all the options I think these three make the most sense to a reader.

1. Passing it around as native size_t like a uint32. There is little room for error here. So I THINK this is safe, right? You need to be explicit about re-casting it when you want to use it.

```
uint32_t address = 0;
example_structure_t *str;

find_address(&address);
str = (example_structure_t*) address;
```

2. This does seem to be what void pointers are for. But the number of times I've been bashed in the head with "void pointers are bad" is not null. Is this unsafe in any way?  Returning like this, I lose my ability to return errors other than success/failure by implying if ADDRESS is null or not.

```
void *address;
example_structure_t *str;

address = find_address();
str = address;
```

3. Seems like a good spot for a double pointer. I have a guy that works under me and is just learning C, so I wasn't trying to confuse him just yet.

```
example_structure_t **str;

find_address(str);
```

I know there is a ton of opinion on how this can be done. But is there anything factual in terms of safety or best practice?

Comment: Why not just `example_structure_t *str = find_address();`?

Comment: If the pointer points to a single type, then just use the correct pointer type.  If it may point to any of several different data types, then use `void *`.  If it may be either a data or a function pointer, then strictly speaking, `void *` is not guaranteed to work (functions pointers do not have to be representable as `void *`).

Comment: "void pointers are bad" because they're untyped addresses. If you need your program to return an untyped address (probably a bad idea, but you seem to know what you're doing), then you should use a void pointer.

Comment: Tell me what type did `malloc` return?

Comment: @TomKarzes Make that comment into an answer and I'll edit my post around it for the next dummy like me that comes along. Unlike the other comments here, yours made the point exactly as I was hoping someone would articulate.

Comment: @kiranBiradar If I return the address directly, I lose the ability to return error codes. I have two reasons this function might not work, object not available and memory failed to allocate. So I'd rather put the address in the argument, not as the return type. It's way easier to return the address!

Comment: Strictly speaking, in option 2 you do not lose option for error values. Linux kernel does this on multiple occasions. You might get a pointer that actually contains `-ENOENT` or similar. But after searching many days until finding a few missing checks with `IS_ERR` to avoid accessing such an invalid address and the race condition that created those invalid pointers, I strongly believe there must be a dedicated hell for people using those mechanism. (This reminds me that I still need to dig into LKML habbits and provide a fix for the bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Passing it around as native size_t like a uint32. There is little room
> for error here. So I THINK this is safe, right? You need to be
> explicit about re-casting it when you want to use it.

No, neither `size_t` nor `uint32_t` is certain to be suitable for this purpose, even on 32-bit systems.  The size of an address is not necessarily the same as or smaller than the size of a machine word -- if indeed that is indeed what a `uint32_t` represents in a given implementation -- and there is no guarantee that it will fit in a `size_t` either. If you want to pass addresses around in integer form then you should use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` (from `stdint.h`).  If your implementation does not define these optional types then there might not be any integer type suitable for the purpose.

With that said, however, if you're trying to convey a pointer, then it's odd to propose conveying it other than *as* a pointer.

> This does seem to be what void pointers are for. But the number of
> times I've been bashed in the head with "void pointers are bad" is not
> null. Is this unsafe in any way? Returning like this, I lose my
> ability to return errors other than success/failure by implying if
> ADDRESS is null or not.

It is what `void` pointers are for *if there is no more suitable pointer type*.  If you will always be returning a pointer to a specific data type, on the other hand, then the pointer type should reflect that.  There is nothing inherently unsafe with returning a pointer, target type notwithstanding.

If you need to provide finer-grained status information than success / failure, then you should use an out parameter in addition to the function's return value.  It's your choice, then, whether the pointer or the status code is conveyed via that parameter.

I've no idea what misguided programming philosophy or coding convention might teach that use of type `void *` in C is unconditionally bad.  There are definitely situations in which it is the right thing to do, and they're not all that rare.

> Seems like a good spot for a double pointer. I have a guy that works
> under me and is just learning C, so I wasn't trying to confuse him
> just yet.

That would be the out parameter option already discussed.  There's nothing particularly wrong with that, but if you can do without an out parameter by using the return value, then that's the way I would go, myself.

> I know there is a ton of opinion on how this can be done. But is there anything factual in terms of safety or best practice?

I don't think there's much diversity of opinion about how it *can* be done.  I'm disinclined to believe that many people would disagree that if you specifically want to convey a pointer then you would best do so *as* a pointer, or that you should prefer a more specific pointer type over `void *` where there is one that serves the purpose.  Beyond that, I'd say the details are a matter of project convention, situation-specific requirements, and personal preference.

Comment: That all makes sense, and I'll vote it as an answer. I forgot about uintptr_t. And yes, the idea is working with the integer value of the pointer.

Part of the problem is I really did want to keep the error as the return. So... err = findAddress(someAddressArg); Without using a double pointer, I'm not sure there is a really clean way to do it without the local uintptr created and address passed up as a pointer itself. Unless I'm missing something? Right? At some point it needs to be inside of local memory at the function caller. Even a void* alone doesn't help here I think.

Comment: @mintbranchconditioner, if you want to return a pointer via an out parameter then that parameter's type needs to be a pointer type targeting the (pointer) type of the value to be conveyed.  That's necessarily a double pointer, at least.  If you want your function to have a return value that conveys integer-coded error information then that's fine, but you should then use an out parameter to convey the pointer, as already discussed.  I'm not following the rest of your thought process here, but I assure you that what I describe is possible and fairly natural.

Comment: Yea, that's basically it. I wasn't sure if you could do it any other way than a double pointer - without making an integer of some sort of the address. In this case, because I'm providing the code for someone inexperienced, I'll use a uintptr_t and return the value of the address.

Comment: Of course you'll do what you think best, @mintbranchconditioner, but if it were me, I would attempt to model and teach good coding style to my junior, above and beyond most other considerations. Certainly not something I'm going to want them to unlearn later.